# How to replace where clause dynamically in query (BIRT)?

Tags: sql, where-clause, birt

In my report query I have a where clause that needs to be replaced dynamically based on the data chosen in the front end.

The query is something like :

*where ?=?*

I already have a code to replace the value - I created report parameter and linked to the value ? in the query.

Example: 

*where name=?*

Any value of name that comes from front end replaces the ? in the where clause - this works fine.

But now I need to replace the entire clause (where ?=?). Should I create two parameters and link them to both the '?' ?

Answer (score 5):

No, unfortunately most database engines do not allow to use a query parameter for handling a dynamic column name. This is for security considerations.

So you need to keep an arbitrary column name in the query:

```
where name=?
```

And then in "beforeOpen" script of the dataset replace 'name' with a report parameter value:

```
this.queryText=this.queryText.replace("name",params["myparameter"].value);
```

To prevent SQLIA i recommend to test the value of the parameter in this script. There are many ways to do this but a white list is the strongest test, for example:

```
var column=params["myparameter"].value;
if (column=="name" || column=="id" || column=="account" || column=="mycolumnname"){
  this.queryText=this.queryText.replace("name",column);
}
```

Comment: In my report, the number of input parameters is not fixed, as in the where clause could have only name or name and code or even no where clause at all.
I have to dynamically alter the query based on the parameters coming from front end.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Dominique's answer and your comment, then you'll just need a slightly more advanced logic. 
For example, you could name your dynamic column-name-value pairs (column1, value1), (column2, value2) and so on. In the static text of the query, make sure to have bind variables for value1, value2 and so on (for example, with Oracle SQL, using the syntax

```
with params as (
  select :value1 as value1,
         :value2 as value2 ... 
  from dual
)
select ... 
from params, my_table 
where 1=1 
and ... static conditions....
```

Then, in the beforeOpen script, append conditions to the query text in a loop as needed (the loop left as an exercise to the reader, and don't forget checking the column names for security reasons!):

```
this.queryText += " and " + column_name[i] + "= params.value" + i;
```

This way you can still use bind variables for the comparison values.